# Object has no attribute 'Read' Error: PIL Library

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load an image from a specific URL using the Image.Open() method from the PIL library, however I am getting the following error:

```
'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My code is as follows:

```
image1 = Image.open(requests.get(URL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the [`requests` Quickstart](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

where `r` is a `Response` object such that `r = requests.get(URL)`.